# How to create instance of class in different methods

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Do I have to instantiate description every time for different method? Or should I use static? Here's how I'm doing this now: What is the best way of handling this kind of situations. it seems that I repeat this line:`Dim description As BLLDescription = New BLLDescription()` without any good reasn.

```
   Protected Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
            Dim description As BLLDescription = New BLLDescription()
           List<String> = description.GetDescriptionWithoutNotes()
           .....
        End Sub

  Protected Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        Dim description As BLLDescription = New BLLDescription()
       List<String> = description.GetDescriptionWithNotes()
       .....
    End Sub
 Protected Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
            Dim description As BLLDescription = New BLLDescription()
           List<String> = description.GetAllDescriptions()
           .....
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you define BLLDescription as a static class, you can call the GetAllDescriptions() method without having to instantiate:

```
 Protected Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
           List<String> = BLLDescription.GetDescriptionWithoutNotes()
           .....
        End Sub

  Protected Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
       List<String> = BLLDescription.GetDescriptionWithNotes()
       .....
    End Sub
 Protected Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
           List<String> = BLLDescription.GetAllDescriptions()
           .....
        End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, I know. Any reason why I shouldn't do that thoguh?

Comment: Because the data will not be different per instance of BLLDescription, but only used as a data access layer, declaring it as static makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the instance of `BLLDescription` does and how it gets the data.

If it is accessing the same data again and again, you can declare it as static. If it gets same data per request, then have it as a property at the class level.

Comment: BLLDescription calls Function from dataacces layer with aprameters like: BllDescription.GetAllDescription(int number). What do you mean by property at the class level?

Comment: Yeah, so if the parameters change in each invocation, have it as a property on the `Page` Class or somewhere else. That way you can instantiate and open connection in the constructor and each call to `GetAllDescriptions` doesn't have to go through same overhead.